# How to better position ios app in search results?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

You can download it [here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tabu/id1071928642):

As you can see I have a lot of positive votes (726) and almost 5.0 average;)

[image]

The question is why am I displayed to the user behind the apps that have significantly worse number of votes and worst average.

[image]

What can I do to improve position of my app?

Comment: There's a lot of apps with the same name. Use a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to optimize the metadata about your app (such as the subtitle, keywords, etc).

Besides that and the good average rating you have, your ranking is also determined by factors such as the number of downloads, the amount of sales, how long time the app is used for, update frequency and click-through rate.